# $\lambda((a,b)/E)\geq\frac{a-b}{2}$ show that $\lambda(E) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given that $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set of $\Re$ and $\lambda((a,b)\setminus E)\geq\frac{a-b}{2}$(1) (for every $(a,b)\subset \Re$) 
show that $\lambda(E)=0$

What I have tried so far is try to contradict the property 
-$E$ is union of a $F_$ and a set of Lebesgue measure zero 
and specifically show that there can't be $F_$ with the property (1) thus leaving us with a zero measure

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that your hypothesis was supposed to be $\lambda((a,b)\setminus E)\geq\frac{b-a}2$. If so, the Lebesgue density theorem gives the conclusion you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every measurable set $E$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is an open set $O\supset E$ such that $\lambda(O\setminus E)\leq\varepsilon $ (this comes directly from de definition of lebesgue measurable), now $O$ is the disjoint union of countable open intervals so $\lambda(O\setminus E)\geq\lambda (O)/2$ so this implies $$\varepsilon\geq\lambda(O\setminus E)\geq\lambda(O)/2\geq\lambda (E)/2$$
Since $\lambda(E)\leq 2\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\lambda(E)=0$.